# jquery sidebar menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin sidebar menu with horizontal collapse/expand and hopefully drag-n-drop resize.  It would nice if it take the following list for menu options:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">option 1</a></li>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">sub-option A</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href="#">option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">option 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone have recommendations or suggestions?

I like the approach of [jQuerySideBar Plugin](http://sideroad.secret.jp/plugins/jQuerySideBar/) but would prefer something a little simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about an [Accordion](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/).

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

You should also check out jQuery UI's [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) feature.

---

There is a **horizontal accordion** here:

http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html

Comment: I've considered the accordion but can it be changed from vertical to horizontal?

Comment: For that, you need a Carousel. :)  Or a horizontal accordion.  See my edit.

Comment: This is closer to what I'm looking for but a bit overkill with an accordion.  I'll only have a one panel with menu options inside.  Something similar to the jQuerySideBar Plugin http://sideroad.secret.jp/plugins/jQuerySideBar/ but more simple and less buggy.